# Object with a higher renderOrder being clipped by rotated element

Tags: three.js, rendering, z-index

A rotated object (cylinder in this case) cuts off objects (a triangle made by lines in this case) even though the `renderOrder` of the second object is higher. See [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/58/) for the effect.

The triangle should be rendered completely on top of the cylinder but is cut off where the outside of the cylinder intersects with it. It's easier to understand what's happening when a texture is used, but jsfiddle is bad at using external images.

```
var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true, 
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true 
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x24132E, 1);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 7);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position)
  scene.add(camera);

  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 100, 32, 1, true);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
  });

  material.side = THREE.DoubleSide; 
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(mesh);



  var c = 3, // Side length of the triangle
    a = c / 2,
    b = Math.sqrt(c * c - a * a),
    yOffset = -b / 3; // The vertical offset (if 0, triangle is on x axis)

  // Draw the red triangle
  var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
  geo.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(0, b + yOffset, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-a, 0 + yOffset, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(a, 0 + yOffset, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, b + yOffset, 0)
  );

  var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    linewidth: 5,
    linejoin: "miter"
  });

  plane = new THREE.Line(geo, lineMaterial);
  // Place it on top of the cylinder
  plane.renderOrder = 2; // This should override any clipping, right?
  scene.add(plane);
}


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: you can use base64 images in jsfiddle as textures.not sure but some parts of the triangle is inside the cylinder and both objects are visible.so should triangle visible completely ?

Comment: here is the updated code with texture and orbit control http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/60/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the effect that you want use a second scene and render it onto the first one

```
function init(){
    .....
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    scene.add(tube);
    overlayScene.add(triangle);
    .....
}

function render() {
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    renderer.clearDepth();
    renderer.render(overlayScene, camera);
}
```

renderOrder does not mean what you think it means, look at the implementation in [WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js)
objects are sorted by the order, if it meant what you anticipated from it, there would always be some fixed rendering order and colliding objects would be seen through each other, renderOrder is AFAIK used when you have issues with order of transparent/ not opaque objects

Comment: This [doesn't seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/68/). It draws the triangle, but overlays the original scene (therefore defeating the purpose)

Comment: in the fiddle you forgot `renderer.autoClear = false;`

Comment: Good catch. I'd prefer a method that doesn't require 2 scenes as it will likely cause me to create more scenes in the future due to more layers, but it does work

Comment: you can also try experimenting with `material.polygonOffset = true;`, `material.polygonOffsetFactor = some value` and `material.polygonOffsetUnits = some value`, it is used for when objects share a plane and they flicker, but with high enough constants you might get a local layering system out of it

Answer (score 0):

I worte a little plugin for three.js for flares for my game. Three.js built-in flares plugin is slow and I preferred not to run another rendering pass which was cutting framerate in half. Here's how I got flares visible on top of objects which were actually in front of them.

Material parameters:

```
{
  side: THREE.FrontSide,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  transparent: true,
  map: flareMap,
  depthWrite: false,
  polygonOffset: true,
  polygonOffsetFactor: -200
}
```

`depthWrite` - set to false

`polygonOffset` - set to true

`polygonOffsetFactor` - give negative number to get object in front of others.       Give it some really high value to be really on top of everything i.e. -10000

Ignore other params, they are needed for my flares